# Instantiate class based on interface string name

Tags: c#, interface

I have a class that implements an interface like this;

```
... = new Location<ICafe>();
... = new Location<IBusiness>();
etc
```

If I want to expand the number of `Location` types I need to edit code at the moment.

Is there a way I can instantiate the class based on the string name of the interface?

So I would get Cafe or Business from the database and I'd like to instantiate the above using the string names of the interface.

**edit**

I should note that I use ICafe, IBusiness etc, later on in code to determine what type of item this is and what to display on screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, reflection will let you do this, but there will be several steps:

- Get a `System.Type` corresponding to the name, for example [`ifaceType = Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)
- Get a `System.Type` corresponding to the generic type template, starting with any set of parameters, for example [`genericType = typeof (Location<ICafe>).GetGenericTypeDefinition()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx)
- Combine the two: [`specificType = genericType.MakeGenericType(ifaceType)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx)
- Create an instance: [`Activator.CreateInstance(specificType)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx)

Comment: That's great but you have hard coded ICafe and I'd like to have the interface as the string.

Comment: It's just a placeholder, to get the generic.

Comment: you could get the generic type by: genericType = typeof(Location<>)

Comment: @mike: .NET allows you to overload based on the number of generic parameters, so you need a way to distinguish e.g. `Func<TR>` vs `Func<T1, T2, T3, TR>`

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't follow. Your code was completely correct but you could get the generic type definition without coupling the code to any specific type (like ICafe). btw The first would be typeof(Func<>) the second typeof(Func<,,,>)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you may benefit from being even more abstract. Is there some reason you can't have a superinterface called:

```
interface IAbstractLocation
```

Then, create your concrete classes using the appropriate interface, but with those interfaces inheriting from the AbstractLocation type:

```
interface ICafe : IAbstractLocation

interface IBusiness : IAbstractLocation
```

You then would have 1 type:

```
...Location<IAbstractLocation>();
```

Which should handle any new type that you might add that inherits from the IAbstractLocation interface.

Comment: But then how do I tell, elsewhere, that this is an ICafe or an IBusiness etc?

Comment: @griegs: That really defeats the purpose of using polymorphism in the first place.  I like to think that I'm not a "religious" programmer, but if you have to know which type your generic argument is or which type actually implements a given interface than I dare you say are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but would calling getClass() on the object tell you the class name?  Also, I agree with Ed S., you might be thinking about this the wrong way ;)  Plus, Java is a typed language, which does restrict what you can do somewhat...

Comment: @griegs: Perhaps you could give us some more info on the overall design at a higher level.  Maybe there is a better solution than reflection (there usually is).

Comment: `extends`?  `getClass()`?  Java?

Comment: @Ben - I feel like an idiot. I didn't check the tags on the question!  Still, correct me if I'm wrong but I think the concepts of polymorphism are very similar if not the same.

Comment: Interface polymorphism is pretty similar, but generics are handled quite differently.